# Firebase getting data

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a social app in swift 3 and I am using Firebase. I have a problem when I am trying to make a like/dislike system. So every post has this definition :

[Firebase post description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwubH.png)

So I am retrieving every post in an array of objects modelled like the Post in the database(POJO). I also have some nested data for the likes/dislikes in the "info" component which again is an array of custom made objects. 
  The problem is that I want to initialise this array of "info" objects as I iterate through all the posts(like a Join from relational databases). How should I solve this problem taking into consideration that Firebase .observe functions are asynchronous... Here is my approach:

```
var postsArray = [Post]()
var userInfoArray = [userInfo]()


func getDataFromServer(){
posts.observe(DataEventType.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let values = snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary


        var postObject = Post()

        //getting posts and storing them into an array
        postObject.initialize(url: values["image"] as! String, userP: values["user"] as! String, earP: values["ear"] as! Bool, eyeP: values["eye"] as! Bool, textP: values["message"] as! String, uuidP: values["uuid"] as! String, keyP: snapshot.key) 

        self.keyArray.append(snapshot.key as! String)



        self.posts.child("\(postObject.key)").child("info").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let info = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{

                var infoForPost = [userInfo]()
                for eachEntry in info{

                //add to an array then set the info value for every post object
                infoForPost.append(eachEntry)


                }

                postObject.setInfo(infoForPost)
            }


        })






        self.postsArray.append(postObject)

        self.tableView.reloadData()


    })
```

I know the code from the second .observe function doesn't work it should be something like pseudo-code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why dont you loop through the info in your first observe closure? I think you dont need the second closure...

Comment: how to do that without another observe function?

Comment: Add `print(snapshot.value)` inside first observer and see what it prints and check that if you get the info array as well or not?

Comment: Actually i get it bu still don't know how to acces it

Comment: check my answer see if it helps you?

Comment: You mean `info` is empty in `values` dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need only to observe post , since in your post you are also getting info , so you can do something like this:

```
 posts.observe(DataEventType.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
           if let values = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {


            var postObject = Post()


            self.keyArray.append(snapshot.key as! String)

            if let ceva = values["info"] as? [String: Any]{
                    print(ceva)



             }
           }

                postObject.setInfo(infoForPost)
       }
```

**Updated:**

To get the further values you can do like this:

```
let values = Array(ceva.values)


for i in 0..<values.count {

        if let singleValue = values[i] as? [String: Any], let approved = singleValue["Approved"], let disapprove = singleValue["disappreove"]  {
                print(approved)
                print(disapprove)
        }



}
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/0mWjYHEj    The output is only:  "ccc" the number of posts I have

Comment: @adiveli if you replace `[[String: Any]]` with `Any` and then try printing info

Comment: "Type Any does not conform to protocol Sequence" Error

Comment: there is no output :(

Comment: Ok , lets do some more debugging, can you show the code where you are entering this info inside firebase

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fnLazbYA   here is the new output. But the question now is how do I acces the approve member for example?

Comment: yes it is. Now i need to get the members for every info Object without needing to know its parent( the username)

Comment: thanks a lot:D . What topic should i search for that thing you created there in swift language:))?

Comment: @adiveli glad I could help, you should learn about optionals, optional binding and dictionary in swift ,check this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html